# Panic; pattern matches no files on VPS service

Tags: go, glob, systemd, go-templates

I'm currently trying to setup my golang application as a service on a Linux VPS. The golang application runs smoothly on my localhost. On the server itself I can start it with `go run main.go` and the application is callable via the ip address.

Service Configuration:

```
[Unit]
Description=vfreight

[Service]
Type=simple
Restart=always
RestartSec=5s
ExecStart=/root/go/src/VFreight/main

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

But when I try to run it as a service, the service always failed.

```
May 13 20:10:31 srv.vfreight.com systemd[1]: Started vfreight.
May 13 20:10:31 srv.vfreight.com main[3167]: panic: html/template: pattern matches no files: `template/*.tmpl`
May 13 20:10:31 srv.vfreight.com main[3167]: goroutine 1 [running]:
May 13 20:10:31 srv.vfreight.com main[3167]: html/template.Must(...)
May 13 20:10:31 srv.vfreight.com main[3167]: /usr/lib/golang/src/html/template/template.go:374
May 13 20:10:31 srv.vfreight.com main[3167]: VFreight/app/controller.init.0()
May 13 20:10:31 srv.vfreight.com main[3167]: /root/go/src/VFreight/app/controller/control.go:21 +0x9e
May 13 20:10:31 srv.vfreight.com systemd[1]: vfreight.service: main process exited, code=exited, status=2/INVALIDARGUMENT
May 13 20:10:31 srv.vfreight.com systemd[1]: Unit vfreight.service entered failed state.
May 13 20:10:31 srv.vfreight.com systemd[1]: vfreight.service failed.
May 13 20:10:36 srv.vfreight.com systemd[1]: vfreight.service holdoff time over, scheduling restart.
May 13 20:10:36 srv.vfreight.com systemd[1]: Stopped vfreight.
```

`func init() { tmpl = template.Must(template.ParseGlob("template/*.tmpl")) }`

I tried to change the `template/*.tmpl` to `../template/*.tmpl` but that doesnt worked.

[go env](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cBYEO.png)

Hopefully someone has an idea to fix this.

Greetings
Chris

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add `WorkingDirectory=` to the directory of your application, where the `template` directory exists.

From [systemd.exec(5)](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.exec.html):

> If not set, defaults to the root directory when systemd is running as a system instance

So your `main` problem is being run at `/` (root) and `ParseGlob` is trying to find stuff at `/template/*.tmpl`.

Comment: The `WorkingDirectory=` fixed everything. Thank you for your help :)